# force Closes sign up activity in android using mySQL and php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, xml

I am trying to make an app that's gonna require user login and user can sign up there. I am using mySQL. My tables are okay. my code doesnt give any compile time error but it gives a lot of run time error AND force Closes whenever click create button which executes HttpPost. Dont know what to do. I am posting my code. Please help with the code and error.

```
package com.example.learning2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final Button crtButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

crtButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), newUser.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

}
```

//newUser.java

```
package com.example.learning2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class newUser extends Activity{

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

EditText idForm;
EditText nameForm;
EditText passForm;

final String url_of_post = "http://localhost/Cab_service/create_user.php";
final String TAG_SUCCESS ="success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sec_view);

idForm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userId);
nameForm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
passForm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userPass);

final Button createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
new createNewUser().execute();
}
});

}

class createNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

protected String doInBackground(String... args){
String pid = idForm.getText().toString();
String user_name = nameForm.getText().toString();
String password = passForm.getText().toString();

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("$pid", pid));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("$user_name", user_name));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("$password", password));

JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_of_post, "POST", params);

Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

try{
int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
if(success==1)
{
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
finish();
}
else
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "UNSuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}catch(JSONException e){ e.printStackTrace();}
return null;
}
}

}
```

//Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.learning2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
android:name="com.example.learning2.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".newUser"
        android:label="Create New User">

    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


</manifest>
```

//Logcat

```
12-25 03:48:42.014: W/KeyCharacterMap(432): No keyboard for id 0
12-25 03:48:42.014: W/KeyCharacterMap(432): Using default keymap: 

/system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-25 03:48:51.835: W/System.err(432): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused`
12-25 03:48:51.835: W/System.err(432):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
12-25 03:48:51.845: W/System.err(432):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-25 03:48:51.845: W/System.err(432):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-25 03:48:51.845: W/System.err(432):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
12-25 03:48:51.845: W/System.err(432):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-25 03:48:51.845: W/System.err(432):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-25 03:48:51.855: W/System.err(432):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-25 03:48:51.855: W/System.err(432):  at com.example.learning2.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:47)
12-25 03:48:51.855: W/System.err(432):  at com.example.learning2.newUser$createNewUser.doInBackground(newUser.java:67)
12-25 03:48:51.855: W/System.err(432):  at com.example.learning2.newUser$createNewUser.doInBackground(newUser.java:1)
12-25 03:48:51.855: W/System.err(432):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-25 03:48:51.855: W/System.err(432):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-25 03:48:51.865: W/System.err(432):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-25 03:48:51.865: W/System.err(432):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-25 03:48:51.865: W/System.err(432):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-25 03:48:51.865: W/System.err(432):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-25 03:48:51.865: W/System.err(432): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused
12-25 03:48:51.875: W/System.err(432):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
12-25 03:48:51.875: W/System.err(432):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
12-25 03:48:51.875: W/System.err(432):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:983)
12-25 03:48:51.875: W/System.err(432):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
12-25 03:48:51.885: W/System.err(432):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
12-25 03:48:51.885: W/System.err(432):  ... 15 more
12-25 03:48:51.895: E/Buffer Error(432): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
12-25 03:48:51.895: E/JSON Parser(432): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
12-25 03:48:51.905: W/dalvikvm(432): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.example.learning2.newUser$createNewUser.doInBackground(newUser.java:69)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.example.learning2.newUser$createNewUser.doInBackground(newUser.java:1)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-25 03:48:51.915: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  ... 4 more
12-25 03:48:54.045: I/Process(432): Sending signal. PID: 432 SIG: 9
```

BTW, I am new android development and dont have much idea about it.

Thanks!

I think the problem is in the newUser class. can u guys check that class for error.

Comment: localhost connection was refused. Make sure you don't have a firewall enabled that is blocking port 80 (assuming you didn't change the HTTP listening port)

Comment: Android can not make connection to localhost on port `80` `12-25 03:48:51.865: W/System.err(432): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused`, both `PHP` server and `android` is on the same machine  ?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra.. I don't remember changing the port. And I can access the local db using PHP page.

Comment: @Noor.. yes both in the same machine. Is 127.0.0.1 for wamp by default ? Cause my PC IP address is different.

Comment: the problem is in the newUser class it doesn't execute any line from that class. I wrote a makeToast line before connecting to the database and it didn't show. @Zarazthuztra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!!

I used 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' in the app but when I run it in emulator it took the 'localhost' as the emulators localhost not my pc's. Connection was ok after I changed the address to my PCs IP.

But thanks anyway.